# How to fill a column using values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

df1 looks like this:

```
chr <- c("1","1","2")
pos <- c("1000","2000","2000")
df1=data.frame(cbind(tmp1,tmp2))
df1

chr    pos
1      1000
1      2000
2      2000
```

df2 looks like this:

```
chr <- c("1","1","1","2","2")
start <- c("500","1500","2500","500","1500")
end <- c("1499","2499","3499","1499","2499")
state <- c("state1", "state2", "state1", "state3", "state4")
df2=data.frame(cbind(chr,start,end,state))
df2

chr start  end  state
1   500    1499 state1
1   1500   2499 state2
1   2500   3499 state1
2   500    1499 state3
2   1500   2499 state4
```

I would like to add a column `state` to the first dataframe, based on the value in column `df1$chr` being the same as `df2$chr` and the value in `df1$pos` being between those in `df2$start` and `df2$end`. The intended end result would look like this:

```
chr    pos     state
1      1000    state1
1      2000    state2
2      2000    state4
```

I know how to do this if the values in `df2$start` were the same as those in `df1$pos`, but it is the range that I am struggling with.

Any tips would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a non-equi join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, state := state, on = .(chr, pos > start, pos < end)]
df1
#   chr  pos  state
#1:   1 1000 state1
#2:   1 2000 state2
#3:   2 2000 state4
```

NOTE: when constructing `data.frame`, avoid `data.frame(cbind` because `cbind` converts to a `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class.  Use the `data.frame` directly.  Another problem with the example data is using a string variable for 'pos', 'start', 'end'.  It should be `numeric` class

#### data

```
chr <- c("1","1","2")
pos <- c(1000,2000,2000)
df1 <- data.frame(chr, pos)
chr <- c("1","1","1","2","2")
start <- c(500,1500,2500,500,1500)
end <- c(1499,2499,3499,1499,2499)
df2 <- data.frame(chr, start, end, state)
```

Comment: I thought `foverlaps()` would be one way. Your way is concise.

Comment: @jazzurro  It can be used as well. non-equi joins is more recent one

Comment: Yeah. I`ve watched a video that Arun was introducing non-equi join somewhere a while ago. Your answer let me remember that.

Comment: @akrun thanks, both for the solution and for the tips on the dataframe!

Answer (score 2):

Being a SQL inclined person, I might go with a `sqldf` option here:

```
library(sqldf)
query <- "select df1.chr, df1.pos, df2.state
          from df1
          left join df2
              on df1.chr = df2.chr and
                 df1.pos between df2.start and df2.end"
df1 <- sqldf(query, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Edit:**

Your `pos`, `start`, and `end` columns should be numeric in my opinion, because you need to do comparisons involving numbers, not text.  So cast them all to numeric and the above solution should work:

```
df1$pos <- as.numeric(df1$pos)
df2$start <- as.numeric(df2$start)
df2$end <- as.numeric(df2$end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I do that, though, it does not seem to pick up the state for the first row:

`chr  pos  state`

`1 1000   <NA>`

`1 2000 state2`

`2 2000 state4`

Comment: @ajc I can't explain this.  It should be joining that row.  Maybe your data has a problem of some kind.

Comment: I used the code as above, can you get it to work with my example?

Comment: @ajc I can explain it.  Your columns are actually text, this is why some of the comparisons are failing.  You should either a) make those columns all numeric, or b) make the text the same width.  The second option is ugly, and would involve padding with zeroes all over the place.  I vote for making `pos`, `start`, and `end` numeric.

Comment: thanks, it works now! In my real data these columns were numeric but I failed to include that in the example.